# ProGuard for Android and Retrofit2 Converter Gson?

Tags: android, gson, proguard, retrofit2, android-proguard

i am using ProGuard  in my project but its giving wrong data in new Gson().toJson(Request);

i am getting out put

```
{"a":"manage","b":"689184d4418b6d975d9a8e53105d3382","c":"10","d":"76"}
```

instead of

```
{"username":"manage","password":"689184d4418b6d975d9a8e53105d3382","value":"10","store":"76"}
```

My ProGuard  rule

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.** {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
```

and i am using

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

is there a new recommended ProGuard configuration for retrofit2:converter-gson in Android?

Comment: the easiest would be to keep the classes that you wan to use with gson. otherwise you might want to look if gson has an annotation to give a field a name - this is how i do it in my app using jackson.

Comment: how to keep the classes..Any rule

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you either want to keep the class you are using with gson or use [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

option 1 (keep class)

```
// all classes in a package
-keep class com.example.app.json.** { *; }
// or a specific class
-keep class com.example.app.json.SpecificClass { *; }
```

option 2 (use [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)):

```
public class YourJsonClass{
   @SerializedName("name") String username;

   public MyClass(String username) {
     this.username = username;
   }
 }
```

with the second option proguard still obfuscates the class and field names but gosn can use the annotation to get the correct name for each field

Comment: Do we still need { *; } after "-keep class com.example.app.json.SpecificClass" ?

Answer (score 8):

Annotate your JSON model classes with `@Keep`.

Comment: @ralphgabb usually you provide two files with rules to proguard. One from the sdk and one from yoir project. The one from the sdk contains, among others, a rule to keep classes annotated with Keep. Make sure you have that.

Answer (score 5):

Use android @Keep annotation on you desired class like authToken

```
@Keep
data class AuthToken(
    var access_token: String,
    var token_type: String,
    var expires_in: String,
    var userName: String,
    var issued: String,
    var expires: String) {}
```

And then in ProGuard  add below line:
If using androidx

```
-keep @androidx.annotation.Keep public class *
```

Else

```
 -keep @android.support.annotation.Keep public class *
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Moshi for JSON with Retrofit, but the problem was the same. It worked in debug, but after building with ProGuard, the RecyclerView that used the model crashed with a NullPointerException, because the list was full of empty model objects, since Moshi didn't recognize any of the fields. I think the exact same thing happens with Gson.

One solution is to annotate every field with its corresponding serialized name:

```
@Json(name="username") String username;
```

That way ProGuard can obfuscate the variable names without breaking the conversion.

The other solution is adding a "keep" option like Dodge suggested, in the `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-keep public class com.example.model.User
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using jsonschema2pojo every field is annotated with

> @SerializedName(field)

Just add this to your proguard-rules.pro to keep every fieldname by it's @SerializedName.

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```